# It it possible to host two different secure websites on same Linode server instance using nginx?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, linode

Lets say I have two different websites example1.com and example2.com both of which will be secure (HTTPS). I want to host these websites on same Linode server instance (not create two virtual hosts) that has Ubuntu 17.10 OS. I also have nginx as proxy server. How can I achieve this and if same SSL certificate can be used for both sites? Do I need two separate IP addresses on Linode server ?

It is also important that users who visits example1.com should not be able to discover there is example2.com.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally SSL was negotiated before hostnames were exchanged, so years ago you needed different IPs if you wanted to use different SSL certificates.

Then SNI (Server Name Indication) was added to HTTP, which gives an opportunity to exchange the hostname before SSL is negotiated.

That means this should be possible to set up so it will work for anyone with a browser that supports SNI (which today is basically all of them, at least the major ones)